# modify KMail config file

Tags: kubuntu, configuration, kmail

I want to configure the kmail's config file but I am not able to find it. Can you please help me out and point me to where it is on the system.

In Thunderbird I can find it in -- HELP > Troubleshoot Information > Open directory, which points me to the file, I am looking for the same folder/file in Kmail.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact location depends on your system, but you should be able to find it using this command in the terminal:

```
kde4-config --path config --locate kmailrc
```